# How would I pass an alternating color to a component with the Array.map function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am trying to send my child components in a react application an alternating color as a property, and I'm not really sure how to do it. The color of each StatLine component should alternate. I want to use map because my array is dynamic and writing out each row of the array in render seems unnecessary.

```
render() {

const { stats } = this.state;

//var alternatingColor = #d5d5d5;
//var alternatingColor = #a9a9a9;

const Stats = stats.map((season) => {
    return <StatLine color={alternatingColor}  {...season}/>;
});

return (
  <div>
   {Stats}
  </div>
);
```

}

Is there a simple way to do this with the Array.map function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create an array of alternating colors:

```
const alternatingColor = ['#d5d5d5', '#a9a9a9']; // because this is a static array, you can move it out of the component
```

Use the Array#map 2nd parameter to get the index of the item:

```
stats.map((season, index) => {
```

Get the color from the array using the [remainder operator `%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) operator:

```
<StatLine color={alternatingColor[index % alternatingColor.length]} {...season}/>
```

**The render method (not tested):**

```
render() {

  const alternatingColor = ['#d5d5d5', '#a9a9a9']; // you can move it out of the render method

  const Stats = stats.map((season, index) => {
      return <StatLine color={alternatingColor[index % alternatingColor.length]}  {...season}/>;
  });

  return (
    <div>
     {Stats}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: @Kimmiekim  - I'm glad it helped you :)

Answer (score 3):

```
render() {

const { stats } = this.state;

//var alternatingColor = #d5d5d5;
//var alternatingColor = #a9a9a9;

const Stats = stats.map((season, index) => {
    return index %2 == 0 ?  <StatLine color={this.props.color}  {...season}/>
   : <StatLine color={this.props.alternatingColor}  {...season}/>
;
});

return (
  <div>
   {Stats}
  </div>
);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`Array.map` also provides the index of the current element that you can use to alternate between hex values:

```
const Stats = stats.map((season, i) => <StatLine color={ i % 2 ? '#d5d5d5' : '#a9a9a9' } { ...season } />)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you can do it like that:

```
const colors = ['#d5d5d5', '#a9a9a9'] 

const Stats = stats.map((season, index) => {
    return <StatLine color={index % 2 ? colors[0] : colors[1]}  {...season}/>;
});
```

In `Array.prototype.map` callback function the second parameter is an index of the currently iterated item thus you can use it to calculate modulo and apply color accordingly in alternating manner.

Answer (score 0):

```
var alternatingColor;

const Stats = stats.map((season) => {
    alternatingColor = alternatingColor == '#d5d5d5' ? '#a9a9a9' : '#d5d5d5';
    return <StatLine color={alternatingColor}  {...season}/>;
});
```

Comment: alternatingColor is always going to be undefined, so the color will always be '#d5d5d5'

Comment: @csander nope it will only be undefined in the first iteration. note that `alternatingColor` is defined outside of `map` so it will retain any changes to the value.

Comment: Yeah, but there's no assignment happening in your answer